# Unable to stat itself when running a bash script

Tags: bash, stat

I have a bash script called `a` located in `/home/agrillet/` where I do this command:

```
BOOTSTRAP_MODIF="stat -c %Y '/home/agrillet/a'"
```

The output is: `./a: line 60: stat -c %Y '/home/agrillet/a': No such file or directory`

But when I run the same command in my terminal, it works:

```
$ stat -c %Y '/home/agrillet/a'
1517831544
```

I am not running the command as root in both cases, can someone explain what is happening and how to be able to get information about the script while running it?

If I use another command in the script such as `cat /home/agrillet/a`, I am able to print the script from the script itself.

Comment: if that's supposed to be command substitution, you need `$()` around the command.  e.g. `BOOTSTRAP_MODIF="$(stat -c %Y '/home/agrillet/a')"`.   BTW, did you edit that line before posting it - in particular, is there a space character after the `=`?  that's the most likely explanation for the error message you posted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This:

```
BOOTSTRAP_MODIF="stat -c %Y '/home/agrillet/a'"
```

Sets the variable `BOOTSTRAP_MODIF` to the string `stat -c %Y '/home/agrillet/a'`. It doesn't produce any output.

If you expand the variable later, as `"$BOOTSTRAP_MODIF"` (with quotes), you get exactly that string, as one string. The error message looks like Bash trying to execute a command of that name (spaces and all), which you don't have.

You can run the script with `bash -x` (or `sh -x`), or use `set -x` inside the script to see the commands the shell actually tries to run.

See [BashFAQ 050](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050) on how to save a command for later use.

Comment: Thank you, a simple mistake that had me confused due to the message reported. Looking at the error message again, the error line was an important information that I missed: the issue was not while instantiating `BOOTSTRAP_MODIF` but when using it.